# Is this a bug or do I not understand something?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to merge two datasets on their key value and got strange results. I made a simple version to reproduce that problem.

```
df    = pd.DataFrame({'key':[1, 2, 3]})
other = pd.DataFrame({'key':[1, 2, 3]})

df.join(
    other,
    on='key',
    lsuffix='_caller'
)
```

I got this output:

```
    key_caller  key
0   1           2.0
1   2           3.0
2   3           NaN
```

I thought this was strange, so I decided to try this one:

```
df    = pd.DataFrame({'key':[i for i in range(3)]})
other = pd.DataFrame({'key':[i for i in range(3)]})

df.join(
    other,
    on='key',
    lsuffix='_caller'
)
```

And got the result I expected:

```
    key_caller  key
0   0           0
1   1           1
2   2           2
```

If there is no zero then the join is messed up, but if there is zero everything works fine.

So can someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values of the two examples are different. In the first, they are 1, 2, and 3. In the second example, they are 0, 1, 2.

`join` uses the column name in the left dataframe and the index in the right. In the second example, because you used `range`, the index of the right dataframe is identical to the values of key in the left dataframe, so the match is perfect. In the first example, there is no index for 3, so you get NaN, which causes the values to be converted to float.

Comment: @ALollz - I usually don't understand what a pandas doc string means until I've wrestled with a bug for a few hours. [pandas.DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) says _"Column or index level name(s) in the caller to join on the index in other"_. Now I know what that means!

Comment: So, I think the solution would be `df.join(other.set_index('key'), on='key', lsuffix='_caller')` but there is no "key_caller" column, which also makes sense because it matches `key` from left hand side anyway.

Comment: In practice, I often end up calling set_index on the dataframe on the right. The example here, key is the only column, so calling set_index means you are joining an empty dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is because join merge your df's from `df.index` with `other.index`, 
If you pass on parameter is used in other only, the you are doing `df.index == other['key']`

Use merge to indicate columns in both df:

```
pd.merge(df,
     other.rename(columns={'key': 'key_caller'}),
     left_on='key',
     right_on='key_caller'
    )
```

Comment: Merge doesn't have a suffix parameter, so you won't get both columns.

Comment: But, you can use rename inside merge, ( I edited the answer)